# PayPal Express API - Payment date should be greater than current date

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I'm implementing recurring payments into a website but I'm having some issues. My request looks correct from my point of my view however it errors stating the date needs to be later than today which it is.

Here is my request plus response:
[image]

I am on the second last step (Step 4) of this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

You can see the date is: "2016-04-14T00:00:00Z" which is later than today by 2 days.

**Request:**

```
&TOKEN={REMOVED}&PROFILESTARTDATE=2016-04-14T00%3A00%3A00Z&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&PAYERID={REMOVED}&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&AMT=1&CURRENCYCODE=USD&IPADDRESS={REMOVED}
```

**Response:**

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-04-11T23:45:44Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => efe9e7aded581
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 64
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11505
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Start Date should be greater than current date
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Subscription start date should be greater than current date
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

I have tried different formats and I've tried changing my post fields but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

I was `urlencode()`'ing the date. I removed the urlencode and the payment was successful.

Cheers.